# Find all methods in PHP without PHPDoc with regexp

Tags: regex

I want to find all methods which doesn't have got its own comments with regexp.

Lets assume that you have got something like that:

```
class MyClass
{
    public methodWithoutDescription()
    {

    }

    /**
    * This is commented method so i am not intrested in it
    */
    public methodWithDescription()
    {

    }

    public methodWithoutDescription()
    {

    }
}
```

You can notice on the code above that there are two methods whithout PHPDoc and one with it.

There are no problem to find method with comment because you can just use that regexp:

```
(?<=\*\/)\n*.*public.*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KcFfs3/1/)

And that is all.

But how can i search for absence of PHPDoc ? Unfortunately Negative lookbehind doesn't allow to use non fixed width.

P.S. I want to use it in PHPStorm regexp search mechanizm.

Comment: what about `(?<={|})(\s+)public.+$`

Comment: Great answer :) I could not imagine that it would be so simple. Can you post it as normal answer? I will be able to accept your answer in that way. 
If you could add a few words of explanation, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the regex,

```
(?<={|})(\s+)public.+$
```

this will match the functions that were after `{ or }` (with no docs)

`(?<={|})` - positive look behind (matches public after the { or } and any no of spaces `\s+`)

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/KcFfs3/3)

Comment: if one want to use it in PHPStorm it should look like that:
`(?<=\{|\}|;)(\s+)public.+$`
because `}` is registered character in it.